# Showing line breaks if text contains '13' and '10'

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Webapi returns custom text string with `13` and `10` characters for line. If I show this custom text in html, I do not see line breaks (if I use `<pre>` tag, then line breaks are shown).

What should be modified in html or css to show linebreaks? I cannot modify webapi.
I am using knockout data binding to insert values from webapi into html.

```
<p data-bind="text: $data.CustomTxt"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css property "white-space: pre-line":

> Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks